# Unity 3D animations stop working when changing scenes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have two scenes in my game with a door object the player can interact with to go back and forth between the two. I use `DontDestroyOnLoad` to have the player object transition between scenes. On the first scene, I have a chest object that animates open when the player is within interacting range. When starting the game from this scene, the animation works as intended. When I go to the second scene and then back to the first, the animation no longer works even though everything looks as it should.

The animator component (with its animation controller) and my chest script are still on the chest object when I go back to scene 1 and the animator is set to "Always Animate." I am still able to interact with the chest, so being within interaction range to trigger the animation does not seem to be part of the issue.

Here is the script that animates the chest:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chest : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{   
    [SerializeField] private string prompt;
    public string InteractionPrompt => prompt;
    private bool MouseDn = false;
    Animator animator;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        MouseDn = true;
    }

    public void OnMouseUp()
    {
        MouseDn = false;
    }
    public bool Interact(Interactor interactor)
    {
        animator.SetBool("isOpen", true);
        
        if (MouseDn == true)
        {
            MouseDn = false;
            Debug.Log(message:"Opening Chest!");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isOpen", false);
    }
}
```

This uses an interface IInteractable:

```cs
public interface IInteractable
{
    public string InteractionPrompt{ get; }
    public bool Interact(Interactor interactor);
}
```

And the player has a script "Interactor":

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Interactor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform interactionPoint;
    [SerializeField] private float interactionPointRadius = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask interactableMask;

    private readonly Collider[] colliders = new Collider[3];
    [SerializeField] private int numFound;

    private void Update()
    {
        numFound = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(interactionPoint.position, interactionPointRadius, colliders, interactableMask);

        if (numFound > 0)
        {
            var interactable = colliders[0].GetComponent<IInteractable>();
            if (interactable != null)
            {
                interactable.Interact(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code showing how the animation is triggered? There is probably not enough information to answer your question otherwise.

Comment: Your question needs more details. If possible, share the image, game or part of the codes.

Comment: You have `animator.SetBool("isOpen", false);` in `Update`. Since it works before your scene transitions and not after, I'm wondering if this a script execution order issue. Scripts aren't guaranteed to run in any specific order (unless you override the script execution order), so this can lead to inconsistent behavior. Try remove this code from Update and see if you still have the same problem. I'm not sure why you have this in Update but I'm assuming it's because you want a one-shot animation to play. Use animation triggers for this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a script execution order issue, and the ordering of scripts is changing between scenes.
Unity doesn't guarantee script execution order for methods like Update, unless you override the script execution order in your project settings.

**Scenario 1: Chest.Update runs first**

1. `Chest.Update` runs (isOpen = false)
2. `Interactor.Update` runs and calls `Chest.Interact` (isOpen = true)
3. The animator runs and the animation plays because isOpen is true

**Scenario 2: Interactor.Update runs first**

1. `Interactor.Update` runs and calls `Chest.Interact` (isOpen = true)
2. `Chest.Update` runs (isOpen = false)
3. The animator runs and nothing changes because isOpen is false

If you want to play a one-shot animation, I recommend using the `Animator.SetTrigger` method instead of using a bool - then you won't have any timing worries when it needs to be turned off.

Alternatively, you can override the script execution order - but this will quickly get out of hand as these kinds of issues arise and it's usually better to produce code that doesn't break based on Update timing.

And another alternative might be to move some logic to LateUpdate, but again, this is not a scalable solution for a big project.

Comment: The script execution order was exactly the problem. I will be switching to `SetTrigger`. Thank you!

Comment: No worries at all